# Selenium: Dropdown cannot be clicked as it is obscured by button

Tags: c#, selenium, dropdown

I have test cases which selects each option in a dropdown but no matter what I do currently I'm getting this error.

Result Message: System.InvalidOperationException : Element  is not clickable at point (1170.0333251953125,405.4250030517578) because another element  obscures it

```
<div class="btn-group bootstrap-select">
    <button type="button" class="btn dropdown-toggle btn-default" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" data-id="year" title="2018" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="filter-option pull-left">2018</span>&nbsp;
        <span class="bs-caret">
            <span class="caret" />
        </span>
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-menu open" role="combobox" style="max-height: 272px; overflow: hidden; min-height: 0px;">
        <ul class="dropdown-menu inner" role="listbox" aria-expanded="false" style="max-height: 260px; overflow-y: auto; min-height: 0px;">
            <li data-original-index="0" class="selected">
                <a tabindex="0" class="" data-tokens="null" role="option" aria-disabled="false" aria-selected="true">
                    <span class="text">2018</span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok check-mark" />
                </a>
            </li>
            <li data-original-index="1">
                <a tabindex="0" class="" data-tokens="null" role="option" aria-disabled="false" aria-selected="false">
                    <span class="text">2017</span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok check-mark" />
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <select aria-label="view all previous payments" class="selectpicker" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Year must be a number." data-val-required="The Year field is required."  id="year" name="Year" tabindex="-98">
        <option selected="selected" value="2018">2018</option>
        <option value="2017">2017</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Currently trying to change the year with this code -

```
 SelectElement DropDown = new SelectElement(ObjectIdentification);
 DropDown.SelectByValue(ValueToBeSelected);
 return true;
```

With the WebElement being defined like this -

```
 [FindsBy(How = How.XPath, Using = "//*[contains(@class, 'selectpicker')]")]
 private IWebElement DropDownYear { get; set; }
```

[image]

This is what the dropdown looks like when selenium is trying to select pick. Nothing obscuring it that I can see.

Comment: Are you maximizing your browser ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, Here are few options

1. Check if you are maximizing the window -

   ```
    driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
   ```

   OR
2. Use action class to locate and action the element

   ```
   IWebElement element = driver.FindElement(By.Id("year"));
   Actions action = new Actions(driver);
   action.MoveToElement(element);
   var DropDown = new SelectElement(element);
   DropDown.SelectByText("2017");
   ```

Update

3. IJavscript executor

   ```
   IWebElement element = driver.FindElement(By.Id("year"));
   ((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("var select = arguments[0]; for(var i = 0; i < select.options.length; i++){ if(select.options[i].text == arguments[1]){ select.options[i].selected = true; } }", element, "2017");
   ```

Comment: what about option 2 ?

Comment: Its always on the selectbytext line

Comment: @johnc489- Have you tried select by index , select by value ?

Comment: Ah Cool, you can mark it as an answer for future references

Comment: Sure done, also just noticed that this only happens on firefox. Google chrome can use the selectby.

Comment: refer - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Tools_and_testing/Cross_browser_testing/HTML_and_CSS. well ideally, the dev's should refer these so that they code it based on cross browsers

Answer (score 0):

XPath needs to be changed as below

```
//select[@id='year']
```

else,

use the ID or Name locator to select the element

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
var down= driver.FindElement(By.id("year"));
var DropDown = new SelectElement(down);  

//select by value
DropDown .SelectByValue("2017"); 
 // select by text
 DropDown .SelectByText("2017");
```

You can have web element like this :

```
 [FindsBy(How = How.id, Using = "year")]
 private IWebElement DropDownYear { get; set; }
```

**UPDATE :**

```
IList<IWebElement> options= webDriver.FindElements(By.CssSelector("select[id='year']>option"));  
foreach (IWebElement element in options){  
     if(element.GetText().Equals("2017")){  

        element.Click();
    }
    }
```

Comment: Nope, still being obscured by the button apparently. Thanks anyway

Comment: When you run your script , would you able to see the drop down being clicked , or you have to do some kind of manual intervention to see that happening ?

Comment: I can see the firefox window if thats what you mean.

Comment: Yes you can see the Firefox window, in which you must be seeing your script being running. So when your script try to click on drop down and wants to select some value , do you do anything ,any manual intervention ?

Comment: Nope, usually I just let the script run through no manual intervention. This code used to work but I guess the front end devs changed something.

Comment: So how do you handle drop down which is obscured by the button manually ?

Comment: I added an image of the dropdown to main post. There's no actual button obscuring it that I can see, so I just click on the dropdown

Comment: Your question title says it is obscured when trying to click on drop down. There is one more way take every options from drop down in a list and click on element which you want to select.

Comment: Yes that's the error that selenium gives me though, I can't actually see anything obscuring it, but in the front end code it looks like there is.

And yes getting every element in the list was to be my last resort but I guess I will have to.

Comment: Updated the answer with that , you can get the code from there.

Comment: Got the same error on the click with the new code too. -_-

Answer (score 0):

Based on Exception type, You can solve it by using one of the following click method:

```
Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
builder.MoveToElement("Your target element").click().Perform();
```

OR

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;  
js.executeScript("arguments[0].click();","Target Webelement");
```